# Deploy portlets for Liferay 6.1.2 running on JBoss 7.2.0

Tags: deployment, jboss, liferay, portlet

I was wondering if anyone could help me out. I recently installed Liferay 6.1.2 on our JBoss 7.2.0. No problems with setting up the environment. Documentation was really helpful. But now I'm not making any progress with deploying themes and portlets.

Control Panel > Server > Plugin Installations is not providing any upload functions. Only lists of portlets, themes ans templates respectivly and a hint that Liferay marketplace will take over some day.

Letting the JBoss take care of the deployments doesn't work either. This would be my favored solution, but portlet deployments failed because some liferay classes are missing. Tried to deploy a theme afterwards, which didn't result in errors, but this theme was not available for pages in Liferay. Is letting the JBoss take care of the deployments an option anyway? After all portlets cannot run outside of a portal-environment.

My last try so far was using an auto deploy directory. But since our JBoss is running in domain mode instead of standalone, it seems this is not an option. JBoss log states that the deployment-scanner subsystem can only be installed in standalone mode, not in domain mode.

Has anyone extirienced similar problems and can provide a solution or some helpful tips? Or maybe there is an other solution that I haven't tought of so far. Anyway, I looking forward to hearing from you ;-) Thanks in advance.

Regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

Liferay's "Hot Deploy" process ensures that plugins use the correct versions of Liferay libraries, matching the currently installed portal. If your server does not support hot-deployment, there's another, recommended way to inject these settings and libraries. Look at these properties:

```
#
# Set this to true to enable auto deploy of layout templates, portlets, and
# themes.
#
auto.deploy.enabled=true

#
# Set the directory to scan for layout templates, portlets, and themes to
# auto deploy.
#
auto.deploy.deploy.dir=${liferay.home}/deploy

#
# Set the directory where auto deployed WARs are copied to. The application
# server or servlet container must know to listen on that directory.
# Different containers have different hot deploy paths. For example, Tomcat
# listens on "${catalina.base}/webapps" whereas JBoss listens on
# "${jboss.home.dir}/deploy". Set a blank directory to automatically use the
# application server specific directory.
#
auto.deploy.dest.dir=
auto.deploy.default.dest.dir=../webapps
auto.deploy.geronimo.dest.dir=${org.apache.geronimo.home.dir}/deploy
auto.deploy.glassfish.dest.dir=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/autodeploy
auto.deploy.jboss.dest.dir=${jboss.home.dir}/standalone/deployments
auto.deploy.jetty.dest.dir=${jetty.home}/webapps
auto.deploy.jonas.dest.dir=${jonas.base}/deploy
auto.deploy.resin.dest.dir=${resin.home}/webapps
auto.deploy.tomcat.dest.dir=${catalina.base}/webapps
auto.deploy.weblogic.dest.dir=${env.DOMAIN_HOME}/autodeploy
auto.deploy.websphere.dest.dir=${env.USER_INSTALL_ROOT}/wsadmin-deploy
```

You can override these in portal-ext.properties. Configure your JBoss to listen to any directory, here `${liferay.home}/deploy`, and configure its dest dir to somewhere else: `auto.deploy.jboss.dest.dir=${liferay.home}/for-installation-on-jboss`. Then package the resulting content of the dest.dir as *.war or *.ear file and deploy this as usual on your JBoss server. This one will contain all settings and libraries required.

Make sure that `${liferay.home}/for-installation-on-jboss` exists before you try to "deploy" to it.

Comment: Tried these settings on our test-system. But WARs in deploy-folder are not touched by liferay. Haven't changed any JBoss settings though. Do I need to add some deployment scanner settings? As I mentioned domain mode does not support auto deployment (auto deployment does not know which server instance to use as target).

Comment: Afterwards I tried these settings on a local liferay ontop of tomcat. Worked. Created a war-file with data from "/for-installation-on-jboss" and deployed it on our test-jboss. Crashed with error "Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment PrivatePluginInstaller-hook.war".

Comment: Forget my previous two comments. I misconfigured my system a little bit. I fixed that and was able to follow the steps you described. Meaning I created a war file, took it from "/for-installation-on-jboss" on my test-environment and deployed it to my JBoss without any errors. But still there is no effect. I deployed a hook that should add a menu-entry to the control panel (Private Plugin Installer), but this entry is not available. My JBoss is listing two running applications next to my Liferay but both of them are empty.